# Embedding Javascript game as an iFrame in angular app using grunt results in 404 error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, heroku

So I'm trying to embed a project of mine (snake game) in a portfolio site created using Angular with Yeoman/Grunt.

I don't know if this is the **best** way to do this, but, I basically included the project directory (the one I want in the iframe), inside the portfolio application directory (in a scripts folder).

I have success getting it to work on localhost using `grunt serve`.

```
<iframe class="snake-project" src="../scripts/snake/html/play.html"></iframe>
```

As you can see it's just the hardcoded path to the html file. I get a `Cannot GET` error, to `https://sitename.com/scripts/snake/html/play.html`. I'm guessing this is because I tried hardcoding the filepath. I use `grunt build` to concatenate and minify all my files into a `dist` directory.

The app then gets pushed to Heroku and my server uses the `dist` folder. Anyone able to clarify what's the best way to embed a small javascript game like this? Could I do something with `ng-src`?

Comment: I would be almost positive this is an issue with the path to the file. Some things I would try: Have you edited the file on the heroku link within inspect element? Can you verify the link works with a live url?

Comment: @jnolte Yeah I'm actually right in the middle of trying to host the project on a github page so I can use a live url. Seems like the only way I can do this short of editing grunt tasks.